# What does "just down" mean/imply here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

Two people are sitting in a bar. One of them says to the other:

> If you're looking for a place to eat, you should try the cafe **just down** the street.

What does "just down" mean/imply here?

Answer (score 3):

The word ***just*** has a range of meanings - the one applicable to OP's cited context is as per [this definition in Merriam-Webster...](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just)

> **just** 2a:
>    *by a very small margin* : BARELY
>    Example usage: *just too late*

Hence ***just down the road*** means *down the road, but **not very far** down the road* (i.e. - ***nearby***). Note that it's pretty arbitrary whether the place is ***up, down,*** or ***along*** the street (or ***over, across*** if it happens to be on the other side of the thoroughfare). But I'm sure *that* issue will have been covered by earlier ELL questions.

I imagine this *barely, merely* sense arose by extension from the underlying meaning of ***just = exact[ly]*** (whereby *It's **just** enough!* came to imply ***not more*** than enough AS WELL AS ***not less*** than enough).

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, the cafe is on the same street, not too far away. The phrase is *down the street* meaning further along the street that you are on. And the *just* means something like *a little*, though in some situations it might be used more to emphasize that it's easy to get to the place, rather than a reference to distance.